# Scala: Json sorting operations on a json file which has different datatypes but same schema

Tags: json, scala, spray-json

I have a json file which has two types of data for store and online.But datatypes of few columns are different ,but column names and schema are same.
I would like to do some operations on json like sorting,re-arranging using spray joson library in Scala.But I am not able to apply the case class on josn becuase datatype of "storeId" and "amount" are different.
Is there any way we can re-write case class to handle bothe integer and string ?

Example : I will have them in a file, read it line by line and assign it to string

`Given inputJosn String :
{
      "purchaseType": "1",
      "purchaseChannel": "store",
      "storeId": 6167,
      "paymentType": [{
        "type": "CASH",
        "category": "Cash",
        "amount": 3.91
      }]
},
{
      "purchaseType": "2",
      "purchaseChannel": "online",
      "storeId": "6168",
      "paymentType": [{
        "type": "Card",
        "category": "Card",
        "amount": "5.04"
      }]
}`

Code :

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

case class payType(`type`:String,category:String,amount:String)
case class Transactions(purchaseType:String,purchaseChannel:String,storeId:String,paymentType: payType )

object MyJsonpayType extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
implicit val payTypeFormat: JsonFormat[payType] = jsonFormat3(payType)
}
import MyJsonpayType._

object MyJsonTransactions extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
implicit val TransactionsFormat: JsonFormat[Transactions] = jsonFormat4(Transactions)
}
import MyJsonTransactions._



inputJosn.parseJson.convertTo[Transactions]
```

It throws errror saying expecing JsString but got 6167.

I know why is it throwing error, but is these any way to re-writw case class in bettwer way to handle both integer and string.

Comment: type T >: String with Int why can't you use this for storeId?

Answer (score 2):

You can get away with using Either, like

```
case class payType(`type`:String,category:String,amount:Either[Double,String])
```

But then you are simply kicking the can down the road. If you have to do any operation on the amount field like- sort, aggregation you would need to normalise the data.

If that's case I would better write custom de-serialization for the object with having a single type.

Answer (score 0):

In these situations I like to use the Jackson library, but in this situation you could just call the `storeId`:`string`. After that you can parse it to `long` by using a companion object.

Try this:

```
case class Transactions (
  purchaseType:String,
  purchaseChannel:String,
  storeId:String,
  paymentType: payType ) {

  def storeIdToLong(t: Transaction) = TransactionsAsLong(
    purchaseType = t.purchaseType,
    purchaseChannel = t.purchaseChannel,
    storeId = t.storeId.toLong,
    paymentType = t.paymentType
  )
}

case class TransactionsAsLong (
  purchaseType:String,
  purchaseChannel:String,
  storeId:Long,
  paymentType: payType )


object Transactions {
  implicit def transactions_to_long(t: Transactions): TransactionsAsLong = t.storeIdToLong()
}
```

Now you can write `val test: Transaction = TransactionsAsLong(...)` if you need that.

I would suggest to write a custom deserializer instead :-)